# Java Regex User specific characters to be allowed

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to use regex, only allow user specific given password.

i tried this but its not working

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@\\#$%&*()_+\\]\\[';:?.,!^-]{"+MIN_LENGTH+","+MAX_LENGTH+"}$
```

The MIN_LENGTH and MAX_LENGTH are from Database its working min and max lenth case, how can i give the specific uppercase, lowercase, numeric and special characters.

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: For starters, there's usually not a good reason to do this. Passwords should be hashed anyway before storage, and the hash algorithm doesn't care what characters are in the input. Storing actual passwords is a security nightmare.

Comment: you can phrase that question better.

Comment: You want to specify the min/max lengths for uppercased letter, lowercased lotter, digits and special characters, respectively, right?

Comment: What do you need, what is the problem ?

Comment: yes sp00m i need to specify the how many uppercased letter, lowercased lotter, digits and special characters, if the length i am giving {8,16} its working, i dont know but is it possible to specify the length like ^[lowercase][uppercase]{1}[special]{1}[numeric]{1}

Comment: @pradeep Then please edit your question and try to rephrase it to get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid regexes aren't that powerful. You could probably find a solution using a single regex, but it then will be totally unreadable and unscalable. What I suggest you is to separate each constraint logic into a subregex. For example:

```java
public static boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    // 1 to 3 occurrences of lowercased chars
    if (!password.matches("(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){1,3}[^a-z]*")) {
        return false;
    }
    // 2 to 4 occurrences of uppercased chars
    if (!password.matches("(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*")) {
        return false;
    }
    // 3 to 5 occurrences of digits
    if (!password.matches("(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3,5}[^0-9]*")) {
        return false;
    }
    // 4 to 6 occurrences of special chars (simplified to "_", "." or "-")
    if (!password.matches("(?:[^_.-]*[_.-]){4,6}[^_.-]*")) {
        return false;
    }
    // no other kind of chars, and password length from 3 to 20
    if (!password.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,20}")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```